# Difference b/w canvas.drawpath and canvas.drawline

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I want to plot line  within timer. which one shall I use? Is there any performance difference b/w these two? I want plot line within timer which one  is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, if you are in a situation in which you are drawing lots of connected lines (like routes on MapView) try to use "canvas.drawPath". In one of my applications I am drawing nearly 500 routes containing 10.000 points and using "canvas.drawPath" instead of "canvas.drawLine" decreases the drawing time as up to %30.

Comment: I am Drawing line connected at each pixel. means   my one pixel to next pixel there is a line. will it help me?